Excel VBA search for data and stuck at a certain point due to group or split source file?
I have below code which quite simple maybe not the most elegant but works well with a small mistake what I cannot handle. Source excel file is something which I am using with group and split in 4 on my screen due to better visibility. The problem I face with this code, when its run it stops, and there is a

run-time error 1004.

If I push debug I can see that stucks at first empty cell which represents this line wsR.Range("U" & i).Select and if ungroup the section where code has to fulfill missing data, runs further in proper manner, fulfill details and close. I tried with built in ungroup command but not works.
    Sub Dates()

    Dim wbDB, wbR As Workbook
    Dim wsDB, wsR As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB, rngR As Range

    Set wbDB = Workbooks("DASHBOARD.xlsx")
    Set wsDB = wbDB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngDB = wsDB.Range("A:V")

    Set wbR = Workbooks("DATE.xlsm")
    Set wsR = wbR.Worksheets("ENTRY")
    Set rngR = wsR.Range("A:AK")

    Dim j As Long
    j = rngR(rngR.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row
    
    For i = 2 To j
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = rngDB(rngDB.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    
   
    RES = Application.Match(wsR.Range("E" & i).Value, wsDB.Range("B1:B" & lr), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(RES) Then
            
                        
         
            If IsEmpty(wsR.Range("U" & i).Value) Then
                wsR.Range("U" & i).Value = wsDB.Range("R" & RES)
                    wsR.Range("U" & i).Select
                        Selection.NumberFormat = "D-MMM"
                        
            End If
                                                
                    
                        If IsEmpty(wsR.Range("W" & i).Value) Then
                            wsR.Range("W" & i).Value = wsDB.Range("S" & RES)
                                wsR.Range("W" & i).Select
                                    Selection.NumberFormat = "D-MMM"
                        
                        End If
    
    End If
   
    Next i

    End Sub


wsR.Range("U" & i).NumberFormat = "D-MMM" no need to select anything - that's an artifact of the macro recorder.

You don't need to select anything to fill a value or apply a number format.
Sub Dates()

    Dim wbDB, wbR As Workbook
    Dim wsDB, wsR As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB, rngR As Range, RES As Variant, rngMatch As Range
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, lr As Long
    
    Set wbDB = Workbooks("DASHBOARD.xlsx")
    Set wsDB = wbDB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set wbR = Workbooks("DATE.xlsm") 'ThisWorkbook, if code is here
    Set wsR = wbR.Worksheets("ENTRY")
    
    Set rngMatch = wsDB.Range("B1", wsDB.Cells(wsDB.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    
    For i = 2 To wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        RES = Application.Match(wsR.Range("E" & i).Value, rngMatch, 0)
        If Not IsError(RES) Then
            FillIfEmpty wsR.Range("U" & i), wsDB.Cells(RES, "R")
            FillIfEmpty wsR.Range("W" & i), wsDB.Cells(RES, "S")
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

'if rngDest has no value, apply numberformat and fill with value from rngSrc
Sub FillIfEmpty(rngDest As Range, rngSrc As Range)
    With rngDest
        If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
            .NumberFormat = "D-MMM"
            .Value = rngSrc.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Worth reviewing this post to help you avoid select/activate: How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
